# Weird "Receiver not registered" exception

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In onResume() I do:

```
registerReceiver(timeTickReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK));
```

and in onPause():

```
unregisterReceiver(timeTickReceiver);
```

I see "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered" reports in Android Developer Console (there are only 2 reports and my app has thousands of users). The exception is triggered by unregisterReceiver(). What can be happening? I don't feel very confident to just surround it with try-catch.

Comment: On what API version does this happen?

Comment: I don't know, I can't see that in the error reports.

Comment: I'd guess that on some phones the `onResume` event is not always invoked after `onCreate` which in turn causes problems in the first `onPause` for this activity.

Comment: I would tend to agree with Xion, but not a problem with a particular phone...  Instead, I would think it's more of a very specific edge case, such as rotating the orientation at *just* the right time at the start of the activity lifecycle (somewhere very close to onCreate and onResume).  Older versions of the platform have similar problems with dialogs, ViewFlippers, and other widgets -- particularly during rotation, so I'm not surprised that it would happen here too.  Sounds like your code is proper, so I would say just catch the exception.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We've seen this error when doing a long press on a particular screen, and then immediately doing two orientation changes (e.g. turning the device upside down).

The API docs for [unregisterReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver%29) says:

> Unregister a previously registered BroadcastReceiver.

It doesn't say explicitly, but as you've seen, you hit `IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered` if it isn't already registered.

The workaround I'm using is to store my Receiver as a member field, and have it set to null whenever it is not registered, i.e. I initialize it to null, and then only set it when I register it.  This might not be perfect, but it does solve my crashes!

```
private Receiver mReceiver = null;
```

From my onServiceConnected:

```
sLog.debug("Registering receiver");
mReceiver = new Receiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

From my onServiceDisconnected:

```
if (mReceiver == null)
{
  sLog.info("Do not unregister receiver as it was never registered");
}
else
{
  sLog.debug("Unregister receiver");
  unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
  mReceiver = null;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A broadcast receiver should be unregister in the `onPause()` lifecycle method

```
protected void onPause() {
    this.unregisterReceiver(reciever);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: where is the source?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest option would be to wrap try/catch block around the code.

```
try{
    ...
    this.unregisterReceiver(reciever);
   }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there may be some states where the receiver is not actually registered before e.g. a user exits the app.

You might want to try adding a check for the receiver before running unregister, (I've done this in several cases):

```
protected void onPause() {
  if(timeTickReceiver != null) {
    unregisterReceiver(timeTickReceiver);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `BroadcastReceiver` should be registered in the `onCreate()` lifecycle method:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Overrride
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ...
        }
    }

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

And a `BroadcastReceiver` should be unregistered in the `onDestory()` lifecycle method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```

This will prevent the scenario of unregistering a `BroadcastReceiver` that has not yet been registered.

Comment: On destroy could not be called (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29), it's a better idea to bind it onResume-onPause