# Unable to Broadscast uninstall and install intent in android

Tags: android

I am trying broadcast an intent to the application before it is going to uninstall the app. for that i researched and followed some answers in SO.I am able to get the results while installing but when i go back from my app to home the app getting force close because of onStop saying

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.xxx.xxxx}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxx$1@4149f7a8
```

what i have done is,

```
public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity
{                                
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL);
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED);
    intentFilter.addDataScheme("package");
    registerReceiver(NewPackageReceiver, intentFilter);
  }
  private BroadcastReceiver NewPackageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
  {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("DEBUG", " test for application install/uninstall");
        Toast.makeText(AndroidTabLayoutActivity.this,
                "App Install/Uninstall", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

   };
    @Override
   protected void onStop()
   {
    super.onStop();
      unregisterReceiver(NewPackageReceiver);

   }
  }
```

my manifest is

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/locksettings"
    android:label="Locksettings" >
    <receiver android:name=".NewPackageReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"  />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>
```

I am getting log message of installing before launch the app. When i go back to home from app the app is getting force close.could any one point me where i am going wrong?

Comment: try removing unregisterReceiver(NewPackageReceiver);

Comment: You already put this action in NewPackageReceiver then why u need it to implement in  AndroidTabLayoutActivity? Try to put `unregisterReceiver(NewPackageReceiver);` in `onDestroy()`

Comment: it is throwing another error like you for got to unregister the Receiver @KumarGaurav

Comment: try to follow this answer then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978167/weird-receiver-not-registered-exception

Comment: @geet No use. it just avoided force close but i am not getting log while uninstalling

Comment: What you have done in NewPackageReceiver?

Comment: Which Application you are trying to Uninstall? is it "Locksettings" your application  or some other application.

Comment: Can you try to place `unregisterReceiver(NewPackageReceiver);`
 before `super.onStop();` in `onStop();`

Comment: @AnimeshSinha yes it is locksettings same error even i did as you said